# open external application in .Net Form panel

Tags: c#, .net

I want to open an external application in my form like this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrBql.png)

for that I wrote a class to open any applications and set a panel as the parent.

```
    class ApplicationStarter
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        Process app;

        public ApplicationStarter(string path, Panel panel)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                app = Process.Start(psi);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                SetParent(app.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle);
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                MessageBox.Show($"Application is started at {panel.Name}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Write($"Application {path} could not be started {ex.Message}", Log.LogState.FatalError, Log.System.ServerManager);
            }
        }
    }
```

This class opens the application in the correct position and size, but the parent is not set and the application is not in the form.

Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: For .Net UI questions it might make sense to add a Tag like `wpf` or `win-forms` etc.

Comment: You are adding a HWND form to a windows form project.  See similar question at following link : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a437ea8e-9e3c-4233-8763-379144b94551/attach-c-form-to-a-hwnd?forum=winforms